# Strapi media library image url broken by Digital Ocean

Tags: file-upload, digital-ocean, strapi

I am trying to upload an image to Digital Ocean Storage. it's upload in DO but after callback strapi generate wrong URL

for Example:  **https://https//jobsflow/d0e989a489bdc380c55e5846076d07f8.png?updated_at=2022-06-08T17:00:32.934Z** thats mean **https://https//.**

**//jobsflow** is my location of storage.

here is my config/plugins.js code

```
  module.exports = {
upload: {
  config: {
    provider: "strapi-provider-upload-dos",
    providerOptions: {
      key: process.env.DO_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY,
      secret: process.env.DO_SPACE_SECRET_KEY,
      endpoint: process.env.DO_SPACE_ENDPOINT,
      space: process.env.DO_SPACE_BUCKET,
      directory: process.env.DO_SPACE_DIRECTORY,
      cdn: process.env.DO_SPACE_CDN,
    },
  },
},
```

};

//here is my config/middleware.js

```
  module.exports = [
  "strapi::errors",
  {
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "*.digitaloceanspaces.com"
          ],
          "media-src": ["'self'", "data:", "blob:"],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];
```

please help me..! if you have any idea

Comment: I got the same issue, just use the s3 provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a custom upload provider for this?

Why not use the official `@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3` plugin?

```
// path config/plugins.js
  ...
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'aws-s3',
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env('DO_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secretAccessKey: env('DO_ACCESS_SECRET'),
        region: env('DO_REGION'),
        endpoint: env('DO_ENDPOINT'),
        params: {
          Bucket: env('DO_BUCKET'),
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

Another nice trick to change the URL of an image and point it to your CDN is adding this:

```
// src/index.js


async bootstrap({strapi}){

      strapi.db.lifecycles.subscribe({
        models: ['plugin::upload.file'],
        // use cdn url instead of space origin
        async beforeCreate(data) {
          data.params.data.url = data.params.data.url.replace(__ORIGINAL_URL__, __CDN_URL__)

        // you can even do more here like setting policies for the object you're uploading
       
        },
      });


}
```